# Tracking Django Redirect App with Google Analytics

Tags: django, google-analytics

I'm using the Django Redirect app (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/ 
dev/ref/contrib/redirects/) but I'd like to have Google Analytics 
track the urls that's I'm redirecting.  Is there an standard way to do 
something like this without hacking the Django core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roll you're own redirect middleware, an add on a paraemeter to the query string like ?redirect_from=whatever.

Then include a piece of javascript that looks for this parameter and fires off the trackPageView described at http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55529

Comment: I was hoping to use the built in redirect app.